# What does image_resizer mean in the Tensorflow Faster RCNN config file

Tags: object-detection

When training a model using Tensorflow Faster RCNN, what will the image_resizer do to the input image? 
Supposing the image_resizer in the Faster_RCNN config file is set as

```
image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 1000
    max_dimension: 1000
  }
}
```

I have one input image **A.jpg** with 1000*1000 pixels, then I do data augmentation by resizing (enlarging) this image by a ratio of 1.2 using a third party tool, which gives me another image **B.jpg** with 1200*1200 pixels.

When these two images are fed into the Faster RCNN model, what will the image resizer do to A.jpg and B.jpg? If I have understood correctly, A.jpg is kept as it is, B.jpg will be resized to 1000*1000, which means the resized B.jpg will be exactly the same image as A.jpg?! So, this kind of image resizing for data augmentation is useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you are enlarging the image to have bigger objects, right?
However, you have to keep in mind at any time if the size is bigger than the input size it will be resized to the input and you may lose the augmentation effect.